# Game Collision-detection FIX

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

I am making a game where it's about clicking on the nearest yellow dot from the green dot.
I got a *list* named **dots**.
You can check out my codepen to see the code I'm using.
My problem is that when you're playing the game, sometimes some of the yellow dots are too close to each other. So I am thinking if it's possible to make a collision-detection or something else, to check if the yellow dots collides?

Here is a picture of my game...
I made a red circle around the problem:
[image]

The link to my codepen project: /lolkie02/pen/PJVOdy?editors=0010

If you wanna try the game, it only works through iPhone or Android browser since I made the buttons etc. 'touchstart' in the javascript.

```js
function getDistance(obj1, obj2) {
  return Math.floor(
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(obj1.cx - obj2.cx, 2) + Math.pow(obj1.cy - obj2.cy, 2))
  );
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function comparator(a, b) {
  if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
  if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
  return 0;
}

function difference(source, toRemove) {
  return source.filter(function(value) {
    return toRemove.indexOf(value) == -1;
  });
}

////////////////
// global vars
////////////////

var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
var dotMatrix = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "circle"
);
var lineMatrix = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
var screenW = window.innerWidth;
var screenH = window.innerHeight;
var totalDist = document.getElementById("distance");

////////////////
// line constructor
////////////////

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  this.x1 = x1;
  this.y1 = y1;
  this.x2 = x2;
  this.y2 = y2;
  this.el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
  this.class = "line";
  this.update = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.el.setAttribute("x1", x1 || this.x1);
    this.el.setAttribute("y1", y1 || this.y1);
    this.el.setAttribute("x2", x2 || this.x2);
    this.el.setAttribute("y2", y2 || this.y2);
    this.setAttr("class", this.class);
  };
  this.setAttr = function(attr, value) {
    this.el.setAttribute(attr, value);
  };
  this.append = function() {
    svg.insertBefore(this.el, svg.firstChild);
  };
}

////////////////
// dot constructor
////////////////

function Dot(r, cx, cy) {
  this.r = r;
  this.cx = cx;
  this.cy = cy;
  this.el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  this.class = "dot";
  this.update = function() {
    this.el.setAttribute("r", this.r);
    this.el.setAttribute("cx", this.cx);
    this.el.setAttribute("cy", this.cy);
    this.setAttr("class", this.class);
  };

  // activates a dot
  this.activate = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < dots.num; i++) {
      dots.list[i].setAttr("data-selected", "false");
    }
    this.setAttr("data-selected", "true");
  };

  this.visited = function() {
    this.setAttr("data-visited", "true");
  };

  // sets attribute to element
  this.setAttr = function(attr, value) {
    this.el.setAttribute(attr, value);
  };

  // gets attribute to element
  this.getAttr = function(attr) {
    return this.el.getAttribute(attr);
  };

  // appends element to svg and attaches event listeners
  this.append = function() {
    svg.appendChild(this.el);
    this.el.addEventListener("touchstart", this.onClick);
  };

  // on click on element
  this.onClick = function(event) {
    //gets the id and the coords of the dot
    var thisId = Number(event.target.getAttribute("data-id").substr(3, 2));
    var thisCx = dots.list[thisId].cx;
    var thisCy = dots.list[thisId].cy;

    // calculates the distance between dots
    var distances = [];
    for (i = 0; i < dots.num; i++) {
      distances[i] = [i, getDistance(dots.selected, dots.list[i])];
    }
    distances.sort(comparator);
    distances.splice(0, 1);
    var distancesLeft = [];
    for (i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
      if (dots.left.includes(distances[i][0])) {
        distancesLeft.push(distances[i][0]);
      }
    }

    //if the element is the nearest
    if (thisId == distancesLeft[0] && dots.left.includes(thisId)) {
      // calculates distances
      var newDistance = getDistance(dots.list[thisId], dots.selected);

      app.score.update(1); // punteggio x numero di poi
      // app.score.update(newDistance); punteggio x distanza

      //sets the active class to the selected dot
      dots.list[thisId].activate();
      dots.list[thisId].visited();

      // creates the line
      lines.list.push(
        new Line(
          dots.selected.cx,
          dots.selected.cy,
          dots.list[thisId].cx,
          dots.list[thisId].cy
        )
      );
      lines.list[lines.list.length - 1].update();
      lines.list[lines.list.length - 1].append();

      // creates the preview line
      //TODO: eliminare le vecchie preline che rimangono vive

      svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function prelineMove(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        app.preline.update(thisCx, thisCy, mouseX, mouseY);
      });

      //saves the selected dots coordinates
      dots.selected.id = thisId;
      dots.selected.cx = thisCx;
      dots.selected.cy = thisCy;

      //removes the dot from the list of remaining dots
      for (i = 0; i < dots.left.length; i++) {
        if (dots.left[i] === thisId) {
          dots.left.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }

      if (dots.left.length == 0) {
        app.end(true);
      }
    } else {
      app.end(false);
    }
  };
}

////////////////
// lines group
////////////////

var lines = {
  list: []
};

////////////////
// dots group
////////////////

var dots = {};
dots.num = 20;
dots.list = [];
dots.start = 0;
dots.selected = {};
dots.selected.id = dots.start;
dots.left = [];
dots.preline;

////////////////
// app
////////////////

var app = {};

app.level = 2;

app.score = {};
app.score.number = 0;
app.score.el = document.getElementById("score");
app.score.update = function(score) {
  app.score.number += score;
  app.score.el.textContent = app.score.number;
};

app.score.reset = function() {
  app.score.number = 0;
  app.score.update(0);
};

app.results = function(points) {
  if (points == "reset") {
    sessionStorage.setItem("results", 0);
  } else {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("results")) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("results", points);
    } else {
      var newscore = points;
      sessionStorage.setItem("results", newscore);
    }
  }
};

app.launchScreen = function(lastScore, title, description, btnText) {
  app.launchScreen.el = document.getElementById("launch-screen");
  app.launchScreen.el.setAttribute("class", "is-visible");

  var launchScreenTitle = document.getElementById("launch-screen__title");
  launchScreenTitle.textContent = title;

  var launchScreenDescription = document.getElementById(
    "launch-screen__description"
  );
  launchScreenDescription.textContent = description;

  app.launchScreen.btn = document.getElementById("start-btn");
  app.launchScreen.btn.textContent = btnText;

  app.launchScreen.btn.addEventListener("touchstart", function lauch() {
    app.launchScreen.el.setAttribute("class", "");
    app.start(app.level);
    document.getElementById("score2").style.display = "block";
    app.launchScreen.btn.removeEventListener("touchstart", lauch);
  });
};

app.preline = new Line(0, 0, 200, 200);
app.preline.setAttr("id", "preline");

app.start = function(dotsNum) {
  dots.num = dotsNum;

  for (i = 0; i < dots.num; i++) {
    var cx = getRandomArbitrary(45, screenW - 45);
    var cy = getRandomArbitrary(45, screenH - 45);

    dots.list[i] = new Dot(14, cx, cy);
    dots.list[i].setAttr("data-id", "id-" + i);
    dots.list[i].setAttr(
      "style", 
      "animation-delay:" + i / 10 + "s; transform-origin: " + cx + 'px ' + cy + 'px;');
    dots.list[i].update();
    dots.list[i].append();
    dots.left.push(i);

    if (i == dots.start) {
      dots.selected.cx = dots.list[dots.start].cx;
      dots.selected.cy = dots.list[dots.start].cy;
      dots.list[dots.start].setAttr("class", "dot dot--starting");
      dots.left.splice(i, 1);
    }

    // adds the preline

    app.preline.update(
      dots.selected.cx,
      dots.selected.cy,
      dots.selected.cx,
      dots.selected.cy
    );
    app.preline.append();

    svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function prelineMove(e) {
      mouseX = e.pageX;
      mouseY = e.pageY;
      app.preline.update(dots.selected.cx, dots.selected.cy, mouseX, mouseY);
    });
  }

  // sets starting point
  dots.list[dots.start].setAttr("data-selected", "true");
};

app.end = function(win) {
  if (win) {
    app.level += 2;
    app.results(app.score.number);
  } else {
    app.level = 2;
  }

  dots.list = [];
  dots.selected = {};
  dots.left.length = 0;
  svg.innerHTML = "";

  if (win) {
    app.launchScreen(
      app.score.number,
      "", //"Sådan!",
      "", //"Din score er nu: " + sessionStorage.getItem("results") + ' Det næste level vil blive endnu hårdere.',
      "NÆSTE LEVEL"
    );
  } else {
    app.launchScreen(
      0,
      "", //"ARGH!",
      "", //"Din endelige score blev: " + sessionStorage.getItem("results"),
      "PRØV IGEN"
    );
    app.results("reset");
    app.score.reset();
    var score2 = document.getElementById('score2');
    var number = score2.innerHTML;
    number = 0;
    score2.innerHTML = number;
    document.getElementById("score2").style.display = "none";
  }
};

app.launchScreen(
  0,
  "STIFINDER",
  "Find den tætteste gule prik",
  "SPIL"
);

$('.btn').on('touchstart',function(e,data) {
    var score2 = document.getElementById('score2');
    var number = score2.innerHTML;
    number++;
    score2.innerHTML = number;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pythagorean theorem to determine whether the distance of the centers of two dots are closer (or equal) to the sum of their radii - in that case you have collision.
My answer to the similar question :https://stackoverflow.com/a/46973584/4154250

Comment: Wow! Sounds like you know what to do Orwol! Is it possible you can comment a code special for my project? :)