# Collision detector between several objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, collision-detection

I am trying to make a collisionDetector function that notice when two objects collide. I have done this before, but then it was only one main object, and all the other object were part of an array. So that was no problem, but now I have several individual objects. Is there a way to make a function that notice all collision between several objects? Here is the functions for my objects:

```js
var myBrick1 = new object(brick1.img, brick1.x, brick1.y, brick1.width, brick1.height);
var myBrick2 = new object(brick2.img, brick2.x, brick2.y, brick2.width, brick2.height);
var myBrickV1 = new object(brickV1.img, brickV1.x, brickV1.y, brickV1.width, brickV1.height);
 
function object(img,x,y,width,height){   
  this.Sprite = new Image();        
  this.Sprite.src = img;      
  this.X = x;           
  this.Y = y;
  this.Width = width;
  this.Height = height;

}
 
function drawBrick(whichBrick){   
  ctx.drawImage(whichBrick.Sprite, whichBrick.X, whichBrick.Y, whichBrick.Width, whichBrick.Height);
 }
```

(I use mouseup, mousedown, and mousemove event to make a click and drag function for my objects)

Comment: are you ok with using any externa library like lodash?

Comment: I am not familiar with lodash, but if you recomend this, thats ok with me.

Comment: It is very easy to use, you can use `intersection` and `difference` and other methods according to your need. just give it a try first.

Answer (score 0):

Since your objects are all rectangles, you need only to check if their coordinates overlap (I see you have x, y,width, height, so you have all the data, the rest is a bit of math: show some more effort).

I wrote more detailed answer in a similar post here: [[collision detection for paddle (pong/breaking block game)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46973584/4154250)

Comment: It's not that i dont know how to do it, I just think that my method (where I check every single one of the objects position) is a bit cumbersome. But thanks anyways